# Implementing drag&drop with react for multiple lists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop

I am trying to implement drag&drop with react for multiple lists, but i can't seem to get it work!

My color object change after the drop ,but it doesn't place the item in the exact position.Also while draggig the placeholder is also visible outside the ul valid dropzone.

```
var colors = {
    "a": ["Red", "Green", "Blue"],
    "b": ["Yellow", "Black", "White", "Orange"]
};
var placeholder = document.createElement("li");
placeholder.className = "placeholder";
var List = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            data: this.props.data
        };
    },
    dragStart: function(key, index, e) {
        this.dragged = e.currentTarget;
        this.contentToBeDragged_src = e.currentTarget.parentNode;
        e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
        // Firefox requires dataTransfer data to be set
        e.dataTransfer.setData("text/html", e.currentTarget);
    },
    dragEnd: function(key, index, e) {
        console.log(key + ' ' + index);
        this.dragged.style.display = "block";
        //this.dragged.parentNode.removeChild(placeholder);
        // Update data
        var data = this.state.data;
        var from = Number(this.dragged.dataset.id);
        var to = Number(this.over.dataset.id);
        data[index].splice(0, data[index].splice(from, 1)[0]);
        this.setState({
            data: data
        });
    },
    dragOver: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //this.dragged.style.display = "none";
        if (e.target.className == "placeholder") return;
        this.over = e.target;
        // Inside the dragOver method
        var relY = e.clientY - this.over.offsetTop;
        var height = this.over.offsetHeight / 2;
        var parent = e.target.parentNode;
        if (relY > height) {
            this.nodePlacement = "after";
            parent.insertBefore(placeholder, e.target.nextElementSibling);
        } else if (relY < height) {
            this.nodePlacement = "before"
            parent.insertBefore(placeholder, e.target);
        }
    },
    render: function() {
        var context = this;
        var lists = Object.keys(context.state.data).map(function(key) {
            return <ul onDragOver = {
                    context.dragOver
                } > {
                    context.state.data[key].map(function(item, i) {
                        return ( <
                            li data - id = {
                                i
                            }
                            key = {
                                i
                            }
                            draggable = "true"
                            onDragEnd = {
                                (evt) => context.dragEnd(key, i, evt)
                            }
                            onDragStart = {
                                (evt) => context.dragStart(key, i, evt)
                            } >
                            {
                                item
                            } <
                            /li>
                        )
                    }, context)
                } <
                /ul>
        });

        return <div > {
            lists
        } < /div>

    }
});

ReactDOM.render( <
    List data = {
        colors
    }
    />, document.getElementById('app')
);
```

here is a jsfiddle with my attempt at it.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/60rb5dv9/2/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As for the dropping part, the problems are in `dragEnd()` where you write:

```
data[index].splice(0, data[index].splice(from, 1)[0]);
```

The first problem is that you use `data[index]` when you should be using `data[key]` (you don't need the index). The second problem is in your move operation, which probably doesn't do what you expect. Here's what that line should look like:

```
data[key].splice(to, 0, data[key].splice(from, 1)[0]);
```